# phpmyadmin issue in accessing text data stored in a table

Tags: php, mysql, html, phpmyadmin

I'm using a L(inux)A(pache)M(ysql)P(hp) installation to put up a site and am having some problems in accessing data stored as text in a table of my database.

I created a table with 2 fields:

- id: type int, primary key
- text_field: type text

When I try to access the text associated with a certain id

```
$query = "SELECT text_field FROM `table_name` WHERE (id = '$id')";

$query_result = mysql_query($query);

echo $query_result;
```

the output will not be the text stored in the table but the following:

```
"Resource id #5"
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Matteo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first fetch the array

```
$query = "SELECT text_field FROM `table_name` WHERE (id = '$id')";

$query_result = mysql_query($query);

$results=mysql_fetch_array($query_result);

echo $results['text_field'];
```

Comment: It is working, thks. But it will not correctly print special characters as à, è, and so on. What should i do for that?

Comment: In myPhpAdmin, click on 'structure' then click 'edit' on text_field, and change the cooalition to whatever language you are using.

Comment: if that doesnt work, try putting this in the top on your ducoment:  `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is the cause of your erorr, but you do not need to place parenthesis on your tablename as you have it. additionally, you should be escaping your input ($id in this case). As is, your database is open to sql injection.